# Combining two queries in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have the following two queries, one with a number of invoices sorted by date and the other one with a number of receipts

| Customer ID | Trans. Type | Trans. Date | N# | Value | Fiscal Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Invoice | 03/07/2021 | 1 | 20.00 | 2021 |
| 1 | Invoice | 03/07/2020 | 2 | 10.00 | 2020 |
| 1 | Invoice | 14/01/2020 | 3 | 50.00 | 2020 |
| 1 | Invoice | 21/10/2019 | 4 | 200.00 | 2019 |
| 2 | Invoice | 01/10/2018 | 5 | 99.00 | 2018 |

| Customer ID | Trans. Type | Trans. Date | N# | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Receipt | 04/12/2020 | 50 | 260.00 |
| 1 | Receipt | 03/12/2020 | 49 | 110.00 |

My goal is to add one column to the receipt query with the fiscal year the invoice refers to, starting from the more recent ones until the receipt value is reached. The year must be taken from the "Fiscal Year" column.

The following would be the result I want to achieve.

| Customer ID | Trans. Type | Trans. Date | N# | Value | Fiscal Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Receipt | 04/12/2020 | 50 | 11.00 | 2021 |
| 1 | Receipt | 04/12/2020 | 50 | 60.00 | 2020 |
| 1 | Receipt | 04/12/2020 | 50 | 189.00 | 2019 |
| 1 | Receipt | 03/12/2020 | 49 | 11.00 | 2019 |
| 1 | Receipt | 03/12/2020 | 49 | 99.00 | 2018 |

I would like to achieve this with M but the exercise is not trivial for me because the value of the receipt can refer to multiple invoices and I don't know how to split it.

**EDIT**

The second query can have multiple records because there can be several receipts over a period of time for the same customer.
All or part of the first query records can be included in the second query (there cannot be any receipt without having an invoice in first place).

**EDIT 2**

The process combine invoices and receipts of the same customers

The process also assumes that the invoices paid first are the older ones therefore the older invoices are used up first and the invoice balance left is used up by the next receipt.

Comment: Will your 2nd query always have only a **single** record?  And will **all** of the first query records always be included in the second query?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: You didn't answer the most important question.  "the other one with a number of receipts" implies that the second table will have more than one record. How do you determine which items from the first table should be used for the second table when the second table has more than one record?

Comment: What @horseyride wrote.  You do not provide any logic for correlating the records in the second query with the records in the first. As posed, you question is not answerable.

Comment: @horseyride I have edited again my question with your remarks

Comment: Well, it makes sense now, just not sure yet of a great algo to do this

Comment: I believe the example data is still confusing. Your expected result shows $99 for the customer 1 but your original table 1 shows that transaction for customer 2

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer, but I saw this question and it intrigued me.

## Input tables

### fFixTransDate

First, a helper function.

```
each Table.TransformColumns(
  _,
  {
    "Trans. Date”,
    each Date.FromText(_, "dd/MM/yyyy"),
    type date
  }
)
```

### Invoices

```
fFixTransDate(
  Table.FromRows(
    {
      {1, "Invoice", "03/07/2021", 1,  20.00, 2021},
      {1, "Invoice", "03/07/2020", 2,  10.00, 2020},
      {1, "Invoice", "14/01/2020", 3,  50.00, 2020},
      {1, "Invoice", "21/10/2019", 4, 200.00, 2019},
      {2, "Invoice", "01/10/2018", 5,  99.00, 2018}
    },
    type table [
      #"Customer ID" = Int64.Type,
      #"Trans. Type" = text,
      #"Trans. Date” = text,
      #"N#" = Int64.Type,
      Value = number,
      Fiscal Year = Int64.Type
    ]
  )
)
```

### Receipts

```
fFixTransDate(
  Table.FromRows(
    {
      {1, "Receipt", "04/12/2020", 50, 260.00},
      {1, "Receipt", "03/12/2020", 49, 110.00}
    },
    type table [
      #"Customer ID" = Int64.Type,
      #"Trans. Type" = text,
      #"Trans. Date” = text,
      #"N#" = Int64.Type,
      Value = number
    ]
  )
)
```

## Allocations

And now to get what we want.

```
let
  #"Both by Customer ID" = Table.NestedJoin(
    Table.Group(
      Invoices,
      "Customer ID",
      {{”Invoices", each _, Value.Type(Invoices)}}
    ),
    "Customer ID",
    Receipts,
    "Customer ID",
    "Receipts",
    JoinKind.Inner
  ), 

  // Returns a record with two fields: the first row of the table, and the remaining rows of the table
  fNextRow = (t as Table) => if Table.IsEmpty(t) then
    [current = null, remaining = t]
  else
    [current = t{0}, remaining = Table.Skip(t,1)], 

  // reduce r[current][Value] or, if depleted, take the next row from r[remaining]
  fSubtractValue = (r, v) => let
    current = r[current],
    remaining = r[remaining],
    prevValue = current[Value]
  in
    if (prevValue < v) then
      // If code gets here, there's a problem
      error Error.Record("Value too large", "Value to subtract cannot be greater than the current value that's being subtracted from!", [r = r, v = v]}
    else if (prevValue = v) then
      fNextRow(remaining)
    else
      // decrease r[current][Value] by v
      [
        current= current & [Value = prevValue - v],
        remaining = remaining
      ], 

/*
Expects and returns
  [
    Allocation = [ // set but not read by this function.
      #"Customer ID” = Int64.Type,
      #"Trans. Type" = text,
      #"Trans. Date" = date,
      #"N#” = Int64.Type,
      Value = number,
      #"Fiscal Year" = Int64.Type
    ],
    Receipts = [
      current = a receipt record except [Value] represents the amount not yet allocated.
      remaining = table of receipts yet to be allocated
    ],
    Invoices = [
      current = row in Invoices except Value is the amount unpaid by allocated receipts so far,
      remaining = table of Invoices that have no receipts yet allocated to them
    ]
  ]
*/
  fAllocate = each let
    Invoice = [Invoices][current],
    Receipt = [Receipt][current],
    Value = List.Min({
      Invoice[Value],
      Receipt[Value]
    })
  in
    [
      Allocation = [
        #"Customer ID” = Invoice[#"Customer ID”],
        #"Trans. Type" = Receipt[#"Trans. Type"],
        #"Trans. Date" = Receipt[#"Trans. Date"],
        #"N#” = Receipt[#"N#"],
        Value = Value,
        #"Fiscal Year" = Invoice[#"Fiscal Year"]
      ],
      Receipts = fSubtractValue([Receipts], Value),
      Invoices = fSubtractValue([Invoices], Value)
    ], 

  fFirstRow = (t as table) => fNextRow(
    Table.Sort(
      t,
      {"Trans. Date”, Order.Ascending}
    )
  ), 

  #"Add Allocations" = Table.AddColumn(
    #"Both by Customer ID",
    "Allocations",
    each Table.FromRecords(
      List.Generate( // creates a list of allocation records
        // Seed function to get first allocation record, plus the data needed in order to generate the next one
        () => fAllocate([
          Invoices = fFirstRow([Invoices]),
          Receipts = fFirstRow([Receipts])
        ]),
        // condition function
        each [Invoices][current] is not null,
        // next element function
        fAllocate,
        // selector function so List.Generate returns just the allocation records
        each [Allocation]
      )
    ),
    type table [
      #"Customer ID” = Int64.Type,
      #"Trans. Type" = text,
      #"Trans. Date" = date,
      #"N#” = Int64.Type,
      Value = number,
      #"Fiscal Year" = Int64.Type
    ]
  ), 

  // Combine the allocations per customer tables
  Allocations = Table.Combine(
    #"Add Allocations"[Allocations]
  )
in
  Allocations
```

*(Caveat: Not debugged)*